# Windows phone 8 init failure with IBM Worklight

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have a strange behaviour in my Windows phone 8 application based on Worklight.

it works locally but when I deploy it in the production environment sometimes it works and sometimes not. Obviously, the behaviour I have is that the app init success in the first launch, it doesn't work in the seconde launch, it works in the third launch, doesn't work in the forth launch ... one by one.
the difference between the development environment and the production environment is that the first one is running over HTTP and the seconde one is running ever HTTPS.

Notice that it works in the other environments (Android, iOS, BlackBerry)

Any help?

Comment: rider we are also facing the same issue ...did u get the resolution. This issue we are facing in our development also. Please help us to resolve this.

Comment: Hi vishal_g, I'm still working on it, I traced the Init request and the only difference I found between the **WP8** environment and the other environments is that with WP8, the code status is **403** and for the other is **401**. I don't know why?!!! probably this causes the issue.

Comment: What will be the solution for it. Because in my case maximum time i am not able to connect to the server.

Comment: try to increase the timeout connection in the initOptions file

Comment: @ghostrider3, if the above was the solution to your problem, please write it as an answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work for me, thx for help

Comment: @ghostrider3, were you able to resolve this? did you consider opening a PMR?

Comment: No I didn't open a PMR,I fixed it by self figuring out a workaround.

Comment: to expalin what I did. Before calling WL.client.init , I added a procedure call first and then I initialised the WL Client. Obviously, It fixed my problem. I think calling a procedure does initialise the connection between the client and the server, so when the client call WL.Client.init or WL.Client.connect, succeeds to reach the server cause the connection is already initialised.

Comment: @ghostrider3, Would be better to write the above as an Answer so that this question could be resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fix the problem.
So to explain, here, what I did:

Before calling `WL.client.init`, I added a procedure call first (It's like a fake call) and then I initialized the WL Client.

Obviously, It fixed my problem. I think calling a procedure does initialize the connection between the client and the server.

So when the client call WL.Client.init or WL.Client.connect, succeeds to reach the server cause the connection is already initialized.

Comment: It should probably be the other way around, first do a WL.Client.connect, and in its onSuccess, do whichever adapter request you need. WL.Client.connect should take place only once (it generates a session against the Worklight Server).

Comment: calling  WL.Client.connect always fails

Comment: the first request before connect doesn't work but it guarantees that the connect will work for sure, that s why I mentioned in the reply that s just a fake call, you see what I mean?

Comment: i tried the above approach but it didnt work for me at all , i am trying to call `WL.Client.Connect` but its not working in windows 8

Comment: plz refer to my reply, you should call WL.Client.invokeProcedure (which is an unsued procedure) before calling  WL.Client.connect, that will trigger the connection so it won't fail in the next call of WL.Client.connect